# Symfony and assets usage at runtime with Javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, assets

As explained in the official [Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets), in a Twig template one can link to an asset as follows:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="My logo" />
```

which will render the right path to the `logo.png` resource (it depends on the folder where the Symfony2 app lives).

Well, suppose to use a Javascript code that has to load an image at runtime (e.g. as a result from an autocomplete), **how can one achieve in Javascript the same result provided by `asset` function in Twig**?

Some note:

1. Maybe exists something like the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle), but I really ignore it!
2. A dirty way could be to generate the path for a known resource, e.g. the `logo.png` file `<script>var known = {{asset('images/logo.png)')}}</script>` and so retrieve the path by a string replace on variable `known` by replacing string `images/logo.png` with an empty one. But it is a dirty way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just remove the file name from the `asset` function to get an absolute path to a directory:

```html
<script>
    var imgDir = {{ asset('images/') }}
</script>
```

Comment: @JeanValjean yes, but instead of outputting a path to a file and stripping the file name, I suggest that you can use the `asset` function to get a path to a directory too. That means you don't need to strip the filename and that makes this not 'dirty'

Comment: Well, I tested it and it really works! Both answers are right, but this one deserve to be the accepted one, since it relies on a truly Symfony-based solution and doesn't require a specific knowledge of the folders' structure on the production server.

Comment: _"Give to Caesar what belongs to Caesar"_ -- Stackoverflow should be a mine of good things, who makes a question has the responsibility to check the correctness of what marked as accepted!

Comment: If you use `assets_version` (http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-version) you have to remove the last part with the version.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely, that the path from your js file to your image remains invariable. This gives you a possibility to use a 'hardcoded' path in your javascript file.

Example:

```
web
 |
 |--js
 |   |
 |   |--foo.js
 |
 |--images
 |   |
 |   |--pic.jpg
```

In this case, you can access pic.jpg from foo.js by `../images/pic.jpg`
Note, that this solution won't work in your twig view, because in your twig view relative asset urls depend on the route url. This is the reason you need the `asset` function.

Comment: It seems to work. But honestly I tested it in locale and for only one page. I should check it in more pages. **+1 and accepted answer** until one has proof to the contrary!

Answer (score 0):

Twig can render JS files not only HTML. You can create a Twig template which will return the JS file with all the script you need. You can then use all of the Twig's functionality in this script file.

Comment: This is far from my aims! In a JS file I load at runtime the images, I don't know at priori which image will be loaded, nor I belive that returning JS files is a good idea when I can simply return a JSON object (less bytes is better!)